# Timestamp handling function breaks replication

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, database-replication

We need an increasing microseconds timestamp that is NEVER ever allowed to decrease, especially if the time is altered (eg ntp) or on restarts etc. I'm currently forced to use MariaDB 5.5.68 (on CentOS).

Basically it is an implementation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_timestamp

Currently it works like this:

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblboxmicro` (
    `microTime` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL  -- the highest microtime used
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tblboxmicro` (`microTime`) VALUES (0);
```

We create this function in order to use that easily:

```
delimiter //
create function getLamportMicros()
    returns bigint
    reads sql data
begin
    declare ret bigint;
    UPDATE tblboxmicro SET microTime = GREATEST(round(@@SESSION.timestamp * 1000000, 0), microTime+1);
    SELECT microTime into ret FROM tblboxmicro;
    return ret;
end
//
delimiter ;
```

It is used this way (a real life example query from PHP with PDO):

```
INSERT INTO tblboxusers 
(microTime, roleNodeId, 
   userNodeId, boxId, roleId, email, name, notes, meta, cipher, accesscode) 
VALUES (getLamportMicros(),0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

## The problem

Now we want to establish a **cross-master replication** and this function is always breaking the replication. It says

`Slave SQL: Could not execute Update_rows event on table box.tblboxmicro; Can't find record in 'tblboxmicro', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_END_OF_FILE;`

Is there a more clever way to reach our goal in a way that does not break replication? It has to be fast, of course...

Edit: We use MIXED binlog format.

Comment: Note that a timestamp function is expected to return the same value if used several times in the same statement.

Comment: @jarlh I do not see the timestamp function used more than once? Maybe I did not understand...

Comment: It's just a general advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found the issue. Mariadb was not able to correctly replicate the @SESSION timestamp. We changed the getLamportMicros() function like this for making it work:

```
delimiter //
create function getLamportMicros()
    returns bigint
    reads sql data
begin
    declare ret bigint;
    select GREATEST(CAST(1000000*UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp(6)) AS UNSIGNED), microTime+1) into ret from tblboxmicro;
    update tblboxmicro set microTime = GREATEST(ret, microTime);
    return ret;
end
//
delimiter ;
```

This is what I found: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-variables.html

> In statement-based replication, session variables are not replicated
> properly when used in statements that update tables. For example, the
> following sequence of statements do not insert the same data on the
> source and the replica:
>
> SET max_join_size=1000; INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(@@max_join_size);

Thus, by replacing `@@SESSION.timestamp` with the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp(6))` function, it seems to work now. The casting was simply to make it usable for our specific case.